# Dimension of set of alternating n-linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant, multilinear-algebra

I need please revision of my reasoning for this problem: 
"Let $S$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$. Let $V$ be the vector space of all functions from  $S$ into $F$. Let $W$ be the set of alternating $n$-linear functions on $S$.  What is the dimension of $W$?"

Now, I  considered the annihilator of $W$, that is, the set of all $n \times n$ matrices such that 2 rows in them are equal. Let $W^\circ$ be that set. 
The dimension values would be then related by $$ \dim \,W + \dim \,W^\circ = \dim \,V $$ and then I would be able to find the dimension of $W$. But I found very complicated to find the dimension of $W^\circ$. I am not sure if I am thinking in the right direction. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Alas, this won't work: what you call $W^\circ$ is not a vector subspace, and the rank-nullity formula only holds for linear maps, not multilinear maps.

Comment: Hmmm I see. I am supposed to solve this by using linear transforms theory and determinant functions. Do you have an idea of how to proceed in this case? thanks in advance

Comment: You can identify $S$ with $F^{n^2}$ right? There would then be an isomorphism between the space of alternating functions on $S$ and alternating functions on $F^{n^2}$. Do you know the dimension of alternating n-linear functions on $F^n$?

Comment: Also from my understanding of the way the question is written, you're considering multilinear functions on $S$ i.e. of multiple matrices. Yet your approach to the problem makes it seem like the functions operate on multiple columns/rows of one matrix. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Osama Thanks for the help. Yes, I mean functions that operate on multiple rows of one matrix. Based on the chapter I found this problem, I guess that if  $D \in W$ and $D(I) = 1$ too then they are all determinant functions.

Comment: @isccha89 That's right! They're al multiples of the unique determinant function so the dimension of that space would be 1.

Answer (score 5):

Let $D$ and $D'$ be two arbitrary alternating $n$-linear functions from $S$ to $F$.

Now, $D(A)=(\det A)D(I)$ and $D'(A)=(\det A)D'(I)$ where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Then dividing them we can see $D'(A)=C\times D(A)$ where $C$ is a constant.
So $W$ has dimension $1$.